# AWS ALB health checks are failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have configured health checks to my ALB which points to a Jenkins instance, however they are failing:

[image]

I tried sending probes to the instance directly, I get successive 200 codes as below:

[image]

Is it the port 8443 which is messing my health check?
Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I think the health checker will try to connect to `/login` using port 443, not 8443.

Comment: Alternatively, you could configure the health check to expect a different HTTP code when trying to access the 8443 port instead of 200. But not sure if that is smart though. :)